# PHP doesn't parse JSON array in $_POST properly

Tags: php, json

My input JSON string is

```
{"videos": ["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nt4fp43U2ys", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dU26cGlmkRg", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TxvpctgU_s8"]}
```

but PHP doesn't seem to parse it properly, since `var_dump` on `$_POST` returns

```
array(1) {\n  ["videos"]=>\n  string(43) "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TxvpctgU_s8"\n}\n`
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Works for me https://3v4l.org/BE6ov, but that's with JSON directly. You should probably be using `php://input` to get the JSON if it's in the POST body. Perhaps if you show us the request being made we can provide a more detailed explanation.

Comment: How do you send this JSON to server?

Comment: Thank you, using `php://input` was the solution that worked for me!

Comment: Also, I'd really appreciate it if you woudn't just downvote my question straightaway. I think that necessary information has been provided in the question, but in case I'm wrong you could easily ask in a more friendly manner for any clarifications. But, after all, I'm just another "skid" in the community getting downvoted for not exactly knowing what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me the source of the json is outputting newlines "\n". So the parsing is probably not the culprit here, the source is.
Either cleanup the output, or remove the new lines first if you don't control the source.

```php
$decoded = json_decode(trim($jsondata), true);
```

Comment: json_decode handles properly proper new lines, and json_encode can insert proper new lines for pretty-printing the json.

Comment: Oh, did not know that. I think the behavior changed in php7. Either way having "\n" in your json object/array screams dirty source to me :)

Comment: OP did not share their code. so anything goes, either sending, or getting the json. As it stands, the json included by OP is valid.